# Is grammar induction on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Are questions about grammar induction on-topic here?  I believe GI belongs to the subject of machine learning, but not necessarily statistics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I suspect a question may be off-topic for Cross Validated, I often leave a comment like this:

> Welcome to the site, @user31264.  This question seems to be only about
>   `topic ______`. As such it would be off-topic for CV (see our help
>   page).  If you have a substantive question about statistics, please
>   edit to clarify; if not, this Q may have to be be closed.

However, "statistics" in this context is shorthand for *statistics, machine learning, or data visualization*, which is our mandate.  In other words, questions about machine learning are fully on-topic here.  Note that we have a [machine-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag, which is [our fourth most commonly-used tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags), appended to 1469 threads (as of today).  For a full list of the topics that are appropriate for Cross Validated, see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in our help center.

Comment: In other words, yes :-)